# Sum of two numbers with function in haskell

Tags: haskell, sum

I am beginner who wants to learn Haskell! I want to make a function, which has two parameters for input and one for output! The task of the function is to sum two numbers and to return the result! This is my code but it gives a error

```
mygcd :: (a , b) -> c 
mygcd c = a + b 

main = do
a <- readLn
b <-readLn
print $ mygcd (a , b)
```

I will be thankful if you can help me!

Comment: As is your question is poorly formed. Consider reading about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: and the error is?

Comment: I would suggest reading some introduction to haskell syntax. [Learn you a haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: If you want to _sum_ the numbers, why is your function called _gcd_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be confusing type variables which are used in type annotations, and the actual values being passed to the function.

In your definition of mygcd:

```
mygcd c = a + b
```

Unless `a` and `b` are defined elsewhere, this will be an error. In other words, these `a`, `b`, and `c` are different than the `a`, `b`, and `c` mentioned in the type annotation for the function. The ones in the type annotation refer only to *types of variables*.

If it is confusing, you can leave off the type annotation and let the compiler determine it for you.

For instance, if you want a function to add two numbers, it's as simple as this:

```
addTwoNumbers a b = a + b
```

If you load this into GHCi, and check the type with `:t addTwoNumbers`, you'll see that the inferred type is `addTwoNumbers :: Num a => a -> a -> a`.

If you would prefer the function add the contents of a tuple, you can change the definition to

```
addTuple (a, b) = a + b
```

Now the inferred type will be `addTuple :: Num a => (a, a) -> a`

```
mygcd :: Num a => (a, a) -> a
mygcd (a, b) = a + b 

main = do
  a <- readLn
  b <- readLn
  print $ mygcd (a, b)
```

Comment: Please add some context and briefly explain how the above solves the problem.

Comment: You're right. Hopefully the answer is more helpful now.